# How to print all the HTTP/REST requests those hit the Wildfly

Tags: wildfly-8, undertow

If I hit Wildfly with 100 requests it will print both InBound and OutBound messages in server.log

Where are if I hit 1000 requests, around 5% of requests are getting 'Connection refused' and not printing in server.log

So please let me know if there is a way to print all the requests those hit the Wildfly even before Wildfly adds them into queue

We are using Undertow and Wildfly 8.1

Answer (score 0):

Proxy WildFly with any front-end HTTP server (I.e., Apache or Nginx). This way you can keep track of all the requests via your front-end server log.